# Why isn't my alternate string replacement method working?

Tags: python

I got a working solution to this question with my second attempt. But I'm wondering why the first option doesn't work as well.

The question is:

> Complete the function to replace the word test with cat and print the new string

my code (working solution):

```
def replaceTest(mystring):
    answer = mystring.replace("test", "cat")
    print(answer)
    
replaceTest('This is a test') 

# output:
# This is a cat
```

my code (solution that doesn't work):

```
def replaceTest(mystring):
    stringSplit = mystring.split()
    for i in stringSplit:
        if i == 'test':
            i = 'cat'
    answer = " ".join(stringSplit)
    print(answer)
 
print(replaceTest('This is a test'))

# output:
# This is a test
# None
```

I can't see why it doesn't work. I think I'm iterating over each item in the list and saying if that item is test, make it cat instead. And then making the list into a string. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Expanding a bit on the answer below, you seem to be under the impression that `i` is somehow directly tied to `mystring`.  That's not so.  The `split` function create a new list of new strings.  Strings in Python cannot be changed.

Comment: Just to point out that your first solution will replace every substring "test" with "cat", even if it is not an individual word. Thus for example it will replace "I am testing" with "I am cating". This may not be what you intended.

Comment: @TimRoberts "somehow directly tied to `stringSplit`", not `mystring`, since they do correctly join the list of words.

Comment: @printf thats great to know. An important distinction for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `i = 'cat'` you are just assigning to the loop variable, which is then discarded. You need to assign to the original `strinSplit` list (`stringSplit[i] = 'cat'`) where by `i` is the index of stringSplit, obtained from `enumerate`:

```
def replaceTest(mystring):
          stringSplit = mystring.split()
          for i, word in enumerate(stringSplit):
            if word == 'test':
              stringSplit[i] = 'cat'
            answer = " ".join(stringSplit)
          print(answer)

replaceTest('This is a test')
```

---

Some improvements while still using your original logic: Having an index in a loop used to access list elements is awkward and error-prone. In this case (and many others) you can avoid it using a list comprehension instead. Also,  I assume you wouldn't really want to print inside the function but instead return the modified string so you can use it further:

```
def replaceTest(mystring):
    string_split_replace = ["cat" if word == "test" else word 
                            for word in mystring.split()]
    return " ".join(string_split_replace)

print(replaceTest('This is a test'))
```

Comment: "With i = 'cat' you are just assigning to the loop variable, which is then discarded. "  Ahh I didn't know that. Thank you.